# Access spreadsheet via Google API invalid_grant

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets, gmail-api

I have created a google form, and keeping the form result in an excell sheet named `yht_istekler.`
I am using following code snippet. taken from [Create Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API in Google drive in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java) 
Though I am getting following error, what am I doing wrong?

```
  List<TrenSeferScheduleEvent> trenSeferScheduleEventList = new ArrayList<TrenSeferScheduleEvent>();

  URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL;
  SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

  File p12 = new File("./conf/key.p12");

  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  List<String> SCOPES_ARRAY = Arrays.asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds");
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setTransport(httpTransport)
          .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
          .setServiceAccountId("clientID")
          .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES_ARRAY)
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
          .build();

  SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("yht_istekleri");
  service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

**Error :**

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Failed to refresh access token: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory$OAuth2Token.refreshToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:260)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:702)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleService.java:738)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:649)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at com.ahmetk.ticketsystem.yht.dao.TrenSeferScheduleEventDaoImpl.getTrenSeferScheduleEventList(TrenSeferScheduleEventDaoImpl.java:66)
    at com.ahmetk.ticketsystem.yht.dao.TrenSeferScheduleEventDaoImpl.main(TrenSeferScheduleEventDaoImpl.java:149)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `access_type` with the value `offline` to your auth request.

I had a very similar error to this not 2 days ago and this fixed the problem.

Also, just to confirm the `clientID` value should be similar to `@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
They basically expect the `email_address` value from the console api credentials - not the `client_id`

Comment: How can I set access_type? Could you give more specific example_

Comment: I wasn't coding in Java but will see if I can work it out. Also, can I confirm setServiceAccountId has the client ID value from your api credentials in Google developer console?

Comment: yeap I have a clientID and do not want to write it here

Comment: And to confirm its along the lines of @developer.gserviceaccount.com ? I'm wondering if that is actually the issue. Wrong value in client Id (I had that too!)

Comment: Just out of interest, try the 'email address' setting in its place in your code. The one ending @developer.gserviceaccount...

Comment: Ah great. Edited my answer above. I read that even though they label up 'client_id' in the dev console, the actual value they expect is 'email_address' ?!?

Comment: hi if you could mark the answer @mmc18 that'd be great

Comment: sorry I have forgotten to upvote it because of exiting of find the solution :)