# Using setOAuth2Credentials to read and write to data to Google sheets

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have a suite of selenium data driven testcases and I am trying to migrate my test data from Excel to Google Sheets, so apparently I need to use OAuth2.  I have very little understanding in this area and am fairly new to programming with java.

I found this helpful link on stackoverflow: 
[Create Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API in Google drive in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java)

Very helpful, *HOWEVER*, for some reason, Eclipse doesn't like the following line:

```
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

Eclipse reports the following:

> setOAuth2Credentials(credential) is not defined for the type SpreadsheetService.

There is a setOAuthCredential for type SpreadsheetService, but it takes 2 arguments instead of the one shown in the above example (taken from link).

My question is how can I get the example code to work (or at least compile)?  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the cause was due to some local environmental issue in Eclipse.  Not sure exactly what that issue was, but once I recreated a brand new project with the required jar files and the example code, everything started to work beautifully.  Now I am able to read and write data from Google sheets.  Awesome!

Updated: 
Found out the cause was an unnecessary jar file in my java build path.  The offending jar file?  **com.google.gdata.jar** - not sure how that ended up in my project, but when I recreated a new project, I didn't include that file.  So after removing this file from my old project it too ran great.

Comment: i am still facing the same issue. can you please provide sample code with required jar file list.

Answer (score -1):

I found `core-1.47.1.jar` has `setOAuth2Credentials(..)` method defined in `SpreadsheetService`.