# I don't get spreadsheets from Google docs

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

I took example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java). But my code below gives me "No spreadsheets found", though I have several spreadsheets at this url https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full.
I don't understand why I don't get any spreadsheets.

```
String CLIENT_ID = "132465@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
    File p12 = new File("key.p12");
    String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
    final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setServiceAccountId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
            .build();

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("GoogleSheet");

    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No spreadsheets found.");
    }     else {
        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheetEntry = spreadsheets.get(0);
        System.out.println(spreadsheetEntry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should share the spreadsheet created from google drive as follows:

```
client id="132465@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
```

Hope this helps