# Using Google sign in to access Google spreadsheets (or other Google apps) on Android

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-sheets, google-api-client

I'm developing an Android app and added a google sign in feature by following the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Now that the user is logged in I want to be able to read and write to their Google Spreadsheets. I have looked at the spreadsheets API and tells you to use OAuth to authorize requests: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

From the sign in page tutorial:

> The Google Sign-In button authenticates the user and manages the OAuth 2.0 flow, which simplifies your integration with the Google APIs.

I'm trying to use the Google sign in page for the authorization process. I can successfully log in and out of my Google account now using the GoogleApiClient, so I tried adding the following code to access my spreadsheets which I call when the user is signed in:

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

            try {
                URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(urls[0]);
                SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
                List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

                for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
                    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
                }

            } catch (ServiceException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I call it using this line:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
```

But on the service.getFeed call I'm getting the following error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2136)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:320)
    at com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:312)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The solutions I found by looking at past questions did not work. One of them was to do service.setUserCredentials(user, password) before the call, but I don't know how to get that information as I didn't personally implement the OAuth part.

How can I resolve this error and use the google sign in page as my authentication?

---

Comment: With android single sign in feature, you should be able to access spread sheets of the user too. But you should have access to this sheet like it should be shared with you or should be public. Also, include spread sheets API scopes depending on the App requirement. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

Comment: @SGC How would I access the sheets? I am looking to create a spreadsheet for my app if it doesn't already exist in the users spreadsheets then edit the same one whenever they use the app.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd suggest to set the authorization header containing the access token.

```
String accountname = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"; // add more scopes here
String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountname, scope);
service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

Also, please note that if you want to create new sheets you will need more scopes added:

> Additionally, if an application needs to create spreadsheets, or otherwise manipulate their metadata, then the application must also
>   request a Google Drive API scope; see Choose Auth Scopes in the Google
>   Drive API docs for information about the available scopes.

Another thing to try is to use the setOAuth2Credentials method, as described below, shamelessly stolen from [Create Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API in Google drive in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java).

```
   HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
   JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
   String [] scopesArray= {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"}; // add more scopes here
   final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(scopesArray);
   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
     .setTransport(httpTransport)
     .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
     .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
     .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
     .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE)
     .build();

   SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
   service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

Regarding the P12 key file, see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/how-where-to-obtain-a-p12-key-file-from-the-google-developers-console

Other references:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope

Comment: How does this method take advantage of the sign in I implemented?

Comment: Your sign in provides you with an access token that you can later use in the Authorization header of spreadsheet requests. The second example might not use your sign in at all, I'm not sure.

Comment: How do I get an access token? All I have is the GoogleApiClient. I use it to get my access token?

Comment: String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountname, scope);

Comment: Okay, so now that I've set up the header, what can I do with it without having to do the OAuth stuff below? I want to avoid it by using the sign in. At this point I'd want to just be able to start working with sheets.

Comment: The second part with GoogleCredential  is just an alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87660/discussion-between-alin-pandichi-and-zar).