# How do I set OAuth2 Google Credentials for Spreadsheet Service?

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I took example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java#answer-30533517). But my code below gives me "*The method setOAuth2Credentials(GoogleCredential) is undefined for the type SpreadsheetService*".

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException {
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL;
        SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

        File p12 = new File("./key.p12");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("cliend_ID")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                .build();

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Test");

        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential); /////// Error occurs here "The method setOAuth2Credentials(GoogleCredential) is undefined for the type SpreadsheetService"
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No spreadsheets found.");
        }

         SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < spreadsheets.size(); i++) {
            if (spreadsheets.get(i).getTitle().getPlainText().startsWith("ListOfSandboxes")) {
                spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(i);
                System.out.println("Name of editing spreadsheet: " + spreadsheets.get(i).getTitle().getPlainText());
                System.out.println("ID of SpreadSheet: " + i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I simply copied the code and imported the libraries as mentioned but I don't understand why I'm getting such error as below.

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing same problem. Please share if you have got any solution to this issue.

Comment: facing same issue. Please share if anyone has any solution

Answer (score 1):

check that you use correct versions of dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```