# The method setOAuth2Credentials(GoogleCredential) is undefined for the type SpreadsheetService

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I refered Example from link:- [How do I set OAuth2 Google Credentials for Spreadsheet Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918707/how-do-i-set-oauth2-google-credentials-for-spreadsheet-service?rq=1)
2- 
[Create Spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API in Google drive in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483601/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-in-java?lq=1)

Please help me.